# TexShop - Command Down

Tags: mac, texshop, keyboard

The quick-key "Command-down" (<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd>) in TexShop works like an "end" (<kbd>End</kbd>) key on my Mac, and brings me to the end of the document whenever I accidentally hit it.  This is driving me nuts.  Is there any way to suppress this?

Comment: It seems to me that this is a general OSX shortcut, so your question might be better answered on a mac-related Q&A page.

Comment: It's the normal action of the shortcut in all applications which conform to the Apple guidelines.

Answer (score 3):

You can change the meaning of this shortcut for `TeXShop` via Apple's System Preferences.

However, this requires you to set it to some command in the existing set of commands from the menu items. The one I found least useful is `Save Source Position` so the following procedure sets it to that.  Perhaps if you define a `DoNothing` menu item then you could set it to that, but until then this should work:

1. In `System Preferences`, select `Keyboard/Keyboard Shortcuts`
2. Select `Application Shortcuts`. Hit the  <kbd>+</kbd> button
3. In the Applications Pull down select `TeXShop`. If it is not already there, select other and locate the `TeXShop` application, and select <kbd>Add</kbd>.
4. In the Menu title you enter the command you want the desired keystroke to map to.  I chose `Save Source Position`.
5. In the Keyboard Shortcut enter <kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>↓</kbd> and you should see now something similar to (depending on your OS):

   [image]
6. Select <kbd>Add</kbd>.
7. Restart `TeXShop`.

Now selecting "Command-down" <kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>↓</kbd>
will trigger  `Save Source Position`, which will leave you where you were.