# Texshop macro for braces

Tags: macros, texshop, braces

How to insert `\left(` `\right)` by simply typing e.g. 'cmd+m' on **Texshop**.

As an example:

write `2+2` and then 'cmd+m' and the output is:

> `\left(2+2\right)`

Comment: There's no need to have `\left` and `\right` next to the parentheses.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although, the `left` and `right` are *not* needed in this specific example, I was looking for a way to create my own macro and this was the first question the popped up. Now that I have figured it out, here is how you would create such a macro in TexShop:

1. In TeXShop go to `Macros/Open Macro Editor` and a window

   [image]
2. Select:

   [image]
3. Chose a name and in the `Content:` section type

   ```
   \left(#SEL#\right)#INS#
   ```

   and select your shortcut key as `b` (`m` is used to minimize the window):

   [image]
4. Select:

   [image]
5. *Optional:* Next time you go back into the Macro Editor you will see your custom macro listed and selecting it will show you the contents:

   [image]

---

Now if you highlight the `2+2`:

[image]

hit <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>b</kbd> you obtain the desired results:

[image]

### Notes;

- I am currently using v3.57 so if your version is not the same things may be slightly different.
- The `#sel#` portion is represents the selected text and the `#INS#` defines where the cursor should be after the macro completes.  You can select other commands and see how they are coded if you desire to define a more elaborate macro.

## References:

- [Does TeXShop for Mac have key bindings?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82382/does-texshop-for-mac-have-key-bindings)
- [TexShop - Command Down](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45453/texshop-command-down)

Comment: I should have looked at my own answer in [Does TeXShop for Mac have key bindings?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82382/does-texshop-for-mac-have-key-bindings) before figuring this out all over from scratch, but as this still has new content, decide to answer it.